# Inbox and achievement pages open in non-fullscreen mode

Tags: feature-request, android-app

In the android-app on tablet, inbox and achivement pages open in non-full screen:

[image: achivement]

[image: inbox]

My thoughts are if it's possible to show more information without need to scroll or doing another extra actions by user - it should be done.

I don't see any negative effects if these windows will be displayed in fullscreen mode.

- App Version: 1.0.89
- Device Manufacturer: samsung
- Device Model: Nexus 10
- OS Version: 5.1.1 (2640980)

Comment: Perhaps this is by design? These aren't normally full pages on the web version of the site, they're drop downs. They look pretty nice to me.

Comment: @Catija maybe, but on the phone (hi-res) achievement opens in fullscreen.

Comment: Yeh that looks more like a feature than a bug to me :)

Comment: @Cai need to request to add OS/device info when adding a request (not bugs only) via app.

Comment: I didn't mean that this question should be a [feature-request], I just meant that the non-full-screen popup looks like it is intended to be that way (so not a bug)... unless you *really* want it full-screen?

Comment: @Cai why not? I've updated the question.

Comment: Ok fair enough, but I don't see why it should be full-screen (should it be full-screen on desktop too?)

Comment: @Cai my question is for android-app only (entire app works on fullscreen on the device). Web version of SE may be opened in window of any size, so no reason to propagate mobile design approach to the desktop one.

Answer (score 3):

That seems totally okay to me. That dialog isn't full-size on the web site either. I think the smaller form factor of the phone makes it necessary to show it full screen, just as the mobile web site shows it (almost) full screen.

This seems by design to me and in better than a full screen.

Comment: Why "better than a full screen"? Can you explain in more details?

Comment: Because the notifications just contain a few items with their excerpts. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/topbar/inbox) what actually is returned. Not so much you need an entire screen to show it.

Comment: Not so much, but need to scroll yet.